# Outlook Appointment mouse hover screentip customization via VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Whenever you're in a calendar in Outlook, and you hover your mouse over an appointment it shows a little screentip (like in the picture below)

Is there a way to customize the look of this screentip? I would like to add a status field to it, which is linked to a custom UserProperty field so the user doesn't have to double-click the appointment and see it in an inspector.

[image]

Also: is there a way, to color or customize the actual appointment 'bars' in the calendar? I'm not talking about categories. I would like to mark them based on a custom UserProperty. Coloring, or adding a custom icon / flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to customize the popup hint.

To change the appointment color, you can set the named property with the DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82140003` (you can set it using `AppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`). The valid values are

```
0x00000000 None
0x00000001 Red
0x00000002 Blue
0x00000003 Green
0x00000004 Grey
0x00000005 Orange
0x00000006 Cyan
0x00000007 Olive
0x00000008 Purple
0x00000009 Teal
0x0000000A Yellow
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I like this coloring of the appointments in the Calendar view. Is there a way to color tasks in the Task List view? Or show the category color, without actually assigning categories? I want to visually distinguish between completed & incomplete tasks, as well as tasks that are in progress

Comment: Also, when I color an appointment item this way, and I open it in an inspector, I get the following message displayed on the top: 'No Categories (colored by old "Personal" label)' or something similar. Any ways to get rid of that message? It looks like Outlook is not completely supporting this coloring anymore.

Comment: Yes, Outlook now uses categories instead of the color - when a category is created, it is associated with the color.